# Angular NVD3: how to create custom tooltip for OHLC/Candlestick chart?

Tags: angularjs, charts, tooltip, nvd3.js, candlestick-chart

I want to add custom tooltips to Candlestick chart. I modified example with custom tooltip on line chart into this: 
[plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/0CwWHlOsTVEQsJ997oQC?p=preview)

```
tooltip: {
  contentGenerator: function (e) {
      //custom tooltip
  }
}
```

I used tooltip.contentGenerator, but it seems that Candlestick charts should be tooltipped the other way.
I will appreciate any help with custom tooltips on OHLC/Candlestick charts.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me in angular 6:

```
chart: { useInteractiveGuideline: true,  interactiveLayer: {
  tooltip: {
    contentGenerator: (function (data) {
      //custom tooltip
    })
  }
}
```